# Restrict network access programmatically for the current app

Tags: ios, swizzling

Is it possible to swizzle or do something so that no part of the app, even static libraries can not make unwanted internet traffic (and still be approved by Apple reviewing process)? And if there is a way, please describe.

Comment: Just write your app so that it doesn't use the network?

Comment: This is not a solution because I use a third party library (I need it) that makes a request on start-up, and in my app I have an "Off Line Mode" that prohibits all internet access. So i need to restrict network access for my app.

Comment: surely it should be up to the user as to whether they want to be offline or not - they can restrict network access for the whole device or per app

Comment: It is great to have a switch in app to do this not just in the device settings. It is a feature often used by users especially if the app is used a lot with Roaming.

Comment: Again, if the user is concerned about roaming charges they can turn off roaming in settings, or just activate airplane mode

Comment: I did not ask how to restrict network access for the current app. The question is how to "Restrict network access PROGRAMMATICALLY for the current app". Please stop avoiding the question and stop posting useless comments that are obvious. No offence but your comments do not help.